# QT Application getting slow on Raspberry Pi 4 after some time

Tags: performance, pyqt5

I've created a QTApplication that runs on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 2GB of RAM. At first it runs fine but after some time it starts slowing down.

Here's a repository with all the files for the application, the actual version of the code is titled "menu_actualizadonoviembre.py": https://github.com/eortegaa1500/hmi_final_raspberry.git

I've noticed that the windows don't really close after changing to another one. but kind of stack over the last one and that's what it's slowing it down.

Anyone knows how to make the windows close after they change? Or how to make the program faster in general? Or a clue of where should I look for to solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry but questions should be self-contained, without relying on external resources (especially if they are repositories) which may become unavailable or invalid. Please provide a [mre] and include it in your post.